# C produce error if no argument is given in command line

Tags: c, command-line, scanf

In C, how can I produce an error if no arguments are given on the command line? I'm not using `int main(int argc , * char[] argv)`. my main has no input so I'm getting my variable using `scanf("%d", input)`

Comment: Then you're not looking at the command line, you're looking at an *input*  line. What exactly do you mean by "no arguments'? What if the input is "Hello"? Or if the input is not empty, but consists only of spaces?

Comment: If you read input from standard input, there's no way in standard C to know if the user are attempting to give some input or not, all input function will simply block and not return until there's an error (like the user pressing the end-of-file key sequence) or the user simply presses the enter key to give you an empty line as input. If you want to actively poll for keyboard input then you need to use platform-specific functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int input;
  int rc = scanf("%d", &input);
}
```

We can verify that `scanf()` was able to successfully get some input from the user by checking its return value. Only when `rc == 1` has the user properly given us valid input.

If you'd like to know more, I recommend reading [scanf's documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: And if the input syntactically looks like an integer but is outside the range represented by `int`, the behavior is undefined (this is a fundamental flaw of the `*scanf()` functions). The OP probably doesn't need to worry about that at this stage, though.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is inconsistent: if you want to get arguments from the command line, you must define `main` with `argc` and `argv`.

Your prototype for `main` is incorrect, it should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

If the program is run without any command line arguments, `arc` will have the value `1`. You can test it this way:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("error: missing command line arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you define `main` with `int main(void)` you have no portable access to command line arguments.  Reading standard input has nothing to do with command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

well, the definition of your `main` arguments are as follow:

- `argc` is the number of arguments
- `argv` are the argument strings

This means you only need to check if argc is equal to one (the program name only) and output an error ;-)

If you use `int main()` only, you have no way to know.